# Magento 2 Module .phtml needed 100% width on Luma

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I have a Module which added a container under the Luma main menu.

Here's the code:

```
<container name="area1" label="Your New Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-new-container" before="-">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="area1.block" template="Vendor_Module::area1.phtml"/>
</container>
```

My problem is that I need it to go 100% width. See image below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference a container that has full width e.g. `page.top`
so you'll wrap up your code inside `page.top` container which will create full width container

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
<container name="area1" label="Your New Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-new-container" after="navigation.sections">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="area1.block" template="Vendor_Module::area1.phtml"/>
</container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: use before and after directives for positioning. In your case  after="navigation.sections" will go inside your container declaration